# How i can update Click Counter of Record with in select stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to record no of click on Product.I already have a stored procedure that selects the details of products from DB. 
I want to update the viewcount column when the stored procedure whenever it selects the record.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Weportal_sp_Product_SelectOne]
@iProductId int,
@iErrorCode int OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- SELECT an existing row from the table.
update [dbo].[Weportal_Product] set  viewcount =((select viewcount from [dbo].[Weportal_Product] where ProductId=@iProductId)+1) where ProductId=@iProductId;
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Weportal_Product]
WHERE ProductId = @iProductId
-- Get the Error Code for the statement just executed.
SELECT @iErrorCode=@@ERROR
```

I already tried this code update the view counter but by four. Each time the record accessed its increase 4 in view counter column.

I need to select the product record and update the number of views against the products id.

Comment: `Update <table> set viewcount = viewcount + 1 where productid = @productid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this.  Just update the value:

```
update [dbo].[Weportal_Product]
    set viewcount = viewcount + 1
    where ProductId = @iProductId;
```

Comment: Thank you for Replay but the same problem on each access stored procedure increases the Viewcounter by 4

Comment: @HarisZafar . . . That would suggest that you are calling the stored procedure four times.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
update WP SET WP.VIEWCOUNT = P.VIEWCOUNT + 1 
FROM  [dbo].[Weportal_Product] AS WP
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT ProductId, MAX(VIEWCOUNT) AS VIEWCOUNT 
     FROM [dbo].[Weportal_Product] GROUP BY ProductId) AS P 
ON WP.ProductId = P.ProductId     --- you may apply further conditions over there to filter out the results
WHERE WP.ProductId = @iProductId
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Weportal_sp_Product_SelectOne, Line 17
Column 'dbo.Weportal_Product.ProductId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @HarisZafar: Updated my ans, check now